# Data split for train test for a model

Tags: r

I have two vectors and a data frame. I run a random generator as to obtain the split for training and test for a model. (TRUE train while FALSE test sets), if run multiple times the number of TRUE to FALSE changes in number (FALSE ranges from 4 to 8) as well as in position. This is an example, the actual data frame is much larger.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,5,4,1,2,3,5,7,4,2,1,5,6,8,5,3,2,4,6,8,9,0,2)
y <- c(3,5,7,8,4,2,2,5,4,7,9,0,0,7,6,4,2,2,1,4,6,8,9,0,0)
X <- data.frame(x,y)

runif(nrow (X)) <= 0.75
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I would like to find a function or to be able to instruct the generation of the split TRUE and FALSE sequentially with all elements named FALSE found only at the end while prior elements should be TRUE. It should yield something in line with the example below.

```
[1]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  
TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE
```

I Have looked for functions that could do this without luck as a function that serves this purpose createTimeSlices in the caret package implies significant changes in the model which are difficult to implement.

On another hand I have the expression below where I obtain FALSE only at the end once while the rest is random as expected, however I can not come out with an expression that would produce sequentially the number of FALSE as instruted by the split to be found only in the last possitions while prior to this yields TRUE as in the example above.

```
S<- runif(nrow (X)) <=  0.75
S[length(S)] <- FALSE 
while(S[length(S)] [!FALSE]) { S<-runif(nrow (X)) <=  0.75}
train<-print(S)
```

Any help is welcomed

Many thanks

Comment: So you want to pick the bottom 25% of the data frame, but you don't want it to be exactly 25% every time? I'm confused about your approach

Comment: That is correct. The random split for whatever reason does not yield always the same proportion of FALSE to TRUE. In the example it ranges from 4 to 8 the number of FALSE elements

Comment: Why do you need it that way?

Comment: Is not that I need it that way, however is that this is the result of the split produced by runif(nrow (X)) <= 0.75 it does not yield always the same proportion of TRUE to FALSE. I think however the answers below solved the question.

Comment: @Barnaby I just edited my response to remove any randomness -- it always gets as close to 75% or the rows (rounded down).  Is that what you were after?

Comment: Yes both of your solutions are good and applicable, thank you. However I do not know why runif produces such a wide range (in the example from 84% to 68% for an split of 75%). Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but couldn't you do

```
S <- runif(nrow(X)) <= 0.75

sort(S,decreasing = TRUE)
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[19]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

that gives you (approximately) 75% `TRUE` values, always at the front of the vector.

### correction?

It looks like you actually want the first 75% of rows (based on your comment above).  in that case, I'd do this:

```
crit <- floor(nrow(X) * 0.75)
train <- seq_len(nrow(X)) < crit
train

 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `sample`? Anyways, all you need to do is sort your boolean vector:

Base R:

```
X$sample <- runif(nrow(X)) <= 0.75
X[order(X$sample, decreasing=TRUE), ]
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
X %>%
  mutate(sample = runif(nrow(X)) <= 0.75) %>%
  arrange(desc(sample))
```